# ALTER Table in PGAdmin4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I can't seem to find where I can ALTER TABLE from within Pgadmin4; I don't see any options to. I would like to edit the default values for some tables/columns as 0 instead of NULL. Thanks!

Comment: Why not simply run an ALTER TABLE statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right click on the table of interest, then select `properties`

On the `columns` tab, you can add a new one or edit an existing column.

By clicking on the `edit` icon on its left, you gain access to finer controls. Go to the `constraint` tab and there you can set the default value.

[image]

Comment: Any idea if it would set all the previous data already listed as the new default value instead of null? Thanks!